# How to improve/shorten PHP code syntax? Wordpress example

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have used browserstack many times for idea's and bugs. I'm at an ok level now but I like to hone my skills.

The following code is a custom piece of coding I have done to a template. It works perfectly. How can I improve this code? It seems way to long for what I'm trying to achieve. How can I shorten this code?

```
// Display treatments specialism icons that a location is practising

// Fetch all the entries from WP database
function get_specs($location_id) {

    //Register globals
    global $wpdb;

    // The query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta";

    // Get the results array from the query
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    // Assign the results array and iterate 1 by one
    foreach( $results as $results ) {
    $meta_key = $results->meta_key; 

    // Every time the key value is a 'naam' (name) check wether this is the name of a specialism.
    // The names are not gotten by certain id's because or flexibility (Client add more/change spacialisms later without programming intervention)
    if ($meta_key == "naam") {

    // The name value to be compared
    $specialismen_naam = $results->meta_value;

    // Store the ID connected to the found naam for later use
    $specialismen_id = $results->post_id;

    // Fetch the specialism meta_value array of all the locations, all specialisms practised are in 1 array
    $specialismen = get_post_meta($location_id, 'specialiteiten', true);

    // Search location specialism array and compare it with the name value. if it has a match continue
    if (in_array($specialismen_naam, $specialismen)) {

            // Get the specialism image from the earlyer stored id
            $thumbnail_image = get_post_meta( $specialismen_id, 'thumbnail_image', true );
            // Get the link to the specialism page for if clicked
            $link = get_page_link(get_post_meta( $specialismen_id, 'link', true ));
            //display the specialism icon with link to specialism page
            echo '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'. wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_image, array(30,30) ) .'</a></li>';
            }
        }
    }
}

// Get the Locations 

// Fetch the data
function get_location_fp($object_ids) {

    // register globals
    global $wpdb;

    // Query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id = $object_ids";

    // Results
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    foreach( $results as $results ) {
    $meta_key = $results->meta_key; 
    $meta_value = $results->meta_value; 

    // If there is a location thumbnail assigned (has to be), process
    if ($meta_key == "lokatie_thumbnail") {

        // fetch displayed data from event in variable. Telephone, address, name, link to location page
            $telefoonnummer = get_post_meta( $object_ids, 'telefoonnummer', true );
            $adres = get_post_meta( $object_ids, 'adres', true );
            $naam = get_post_meta( $object_ids, 'naam', true );
            $link = get_page_link(get_post_meta( $object_ids, 'link', true ));

        // Fetch thumbnail image of each location
            $thumbnail_image = get_post_meta( $object_ids, 'lokatie_thumbnail', true );

        // Display the location
            echo '<div id="lokatie-fp"><a href="'. $link .'"><div class="lokatie-image">'. wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_image ) .'</div></a><div class="lokatie-gegevens"><h3>'. $naam .'</h3><p>'. $telefoonnummer .'</p><p>'. $adres .'</p>';
        // Add all specialisms that are practised at this location
            echo '<ul>'. get_specs($object_ids) .'</ul></div></div></a>';
        }

    }

}

// Called somewhere in template:
<?php get_location_fp(62);  ?>
<?php get_location_fp(67);  ?>
<?php get_location_fp(105);  ?>
<?php get_location_fp(104);  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indenting your code consistently will make it much easier to read/debug

```
// Display treatments specialism icons that a location is practising

// Fetch all the entries from WP database
function get_specs($location_id) {

    //Register globals
    global $wpdb;

    // The query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta";

    // Get the results array from the query
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    // Assign the results array and iterate 1 by one
    foreach( $results as $results ) {
        $meta_key = $results->meta_key; 

        // Every time the key value is a 'naam' (name) check wether this is the name of a specialism.
        // The names are not gotten by certain id's because or flexibility (Client add more/change spacialisms later without programming intervention)
        if ($meta_key == "naam") {

            // The name value to be compared
            $specialismen_naam = $results->meta_value;

            // Store the ID connected to the found naam for later use
            $specialismen_id = $results->post_id;

            // Fetch the specialism meta_value array of all the locations, all specialisms practised are in 1 array
            $specialismen = get_post_meta($location_id, 'specialiteiten', true);

            // Search location specialism array and compare it with the name value. if it has a match continue
            if (in_array($specialismen_naam, $specialismen)) {

                // Get the specialism image from the earlyer stored id
                $thumbnail_image = get_post_meta( $specialismen_id, 'thumbnail_image', true );
                // Get the link to the specialism page for if clicked
                $link = get_page_link(get_post_meta( $specialismen_id, 'link', true ));
                //display the specialism icon with link to specialism page
                echo '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'. wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_image, array(30,30) ) .'</a></li>';
            }
        }
    }
}

// Get the Locations 

// Fetch the data
function get_location_fp($object_ids) {

    // register globals
    global $wpdb;

    // Query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id = $object_ids";

    // Results
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    foreach( $results as $results ) {
    $meta_key = $results->meta_key; 
    $meta_value = $results->meta_value; 

    // If there is a location thumbnail assigned (has to be), process
    if ($meta_key == "lokatie_thumbnail") {

        // fetch displayed data from event in variable. Telephone, address, name, link to location page
        $telefoonnummer = get_post_meta( $object_ids, 'telefoonnummer', true );
        $adres = get_post_meta( $object_ids, 'adres', true );
        $naam = get_post_meta( $object_ids, 'naam', true );
        $link = get_page_link(get_post_meta( $object_ids, 'link', true ));

        // Fetch thumbnail image of each location
        $thumbnail_image = get_post_meta( $object_ids, 'lokatie_thumbnail', true );

        // Display the location
        echo '<div id="lokatie-fp"><a href="'. $link .'"><div class="lokatie-image">'. wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_image ) .'</div></a><div class="lokatie-gegevens"><h3>'. $naam .'</h3><p>'. $telefoonnummer .'</p><p>'. $adres .'</p>';
        // Add all specialisms that are practised at this location
        echo '<ul>'. get_specs($object_ids) .'</ul></div></div></a>';
    }
}

// Called somewhere in template:
<?php get_location_fp(62);  ?>
<?php get_location_fp(67);  ?>
<?php get_location_fp(105);  ?>
<?php get_location_fp(104);  ?>
```

Sometimes it can be easier to read if you can avoid doing nested if statements, for example:

```
if ($meta_key != "naam") {
    continue;
}
```

directly `echo`ing out can sometimes be a bit confusing and can lead to output being sent when not desired (say if an error occurs). I quite like to build up an array of the output before rendering that:

```
$output = array();
$output[] = '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'. wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_image, array(30,30) ) .'</a></li>';
...
...
echo implode(PHP_EOL,$output);
```

Other than those minor things I'd say its fine. It's really nice and verbose, easy to read, well documented.

As for Jalpa's comments I'd say that its good practice to have the SQL query and the execution of it on different lines, it improves readability. And there's no need for an if condition before the `foreach`, that takes care of itself.

**Edit**
You mentioned your `li`'s are being rendered early. From your function get_specs() you certainly don't want to render anything but here you can `return` your output to the `get_location_fp()` calling function.

```
function get_specs($loctation_id) {
    ...
    $output = array();
    ...
    $output[] = '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'. wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_image, array(30,30) ) .'</a></li>';
    ...
    return implode(PHP_EOL,$output);
}

function get_location_fp($object_ids) {
    ...
    $output[] = '<ul>'. get_specs($object_ids) .'</ul></div></div></a>';
    ...
}
```

By returning the output from `get_specs()` rather than rendering it, it will be inserted between the `ul`s and not before it.

Comment: Wow that is great help, thanks. Especially that 'echo' remark you make. Actually th two lines:         // Display the location
        echo '<div id="lokatie-fp"><a href="'. $link .'"><div class="lokatie-image">'. wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_image ) .'</div></a><div class="lokatie-gegevens"><h3>'. $naam .'</h3><p>'. $telefoonnummer .'</p><p>'. $adres .'</p>';
        // Add all specialisms that are practised at this location
        echo '<ul>'. get_specs($object_ids) .'</ul></div></div></a>';

Comment: Where having a small error when I put them on two lines. The <li> gets echo'd too early and did not get why. By putting it on two rules I kinda got around that. Im going to try your way now to see if I can clean that up. Thanks for the pointout

Comment: I've added an extra edit to help you with that last comment you made.

Comment: p.s. if you find an answer helpful, it's good practice to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add below changes :

1) Please write query like this `$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta")` no need to write in two lines.

2) please put if condition before foreach is not empty or count() array > 0.